# read_html() cannot read a webpage despite specifying different encodings

Tags: r, encoding, rvest

I was trying to read an html page in Japanese into R using the `read_html()` function in the `rvest`/`xml2` package.

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.post.japanpost.jp/kitte_hagaki/stamp/kogata/index.php?p=4"
read_html(url)
```

However, the line of code kept throwing an error message.

```
> read_html(url)
Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xAD 0xA1 0xCD 0xB9 [6003]
```

The function `guess_encoding()` return a list of likely encodings as below whereas the header of the webpage HTML declares `charset=euc-jp`.

```
     encoding language confidence
1  ISO-8859-1       sv       0.31
2  ISO-8859-2       cs       0.22
3       UTF-8                0.15
4  ISO-8859-9       tr       0.13
5    UTF-16BE                0.10
6    UTF-16LE                0.10
7   Shift_JIS       ja       0.10
8     GB18030       zh       0.10
9      EUC-JP       ja       0.10
10     EUC-KR       ko       0.10
11       Big5       zh       0.10
```

Reading the webpage in other encodings, such as `EUC-JP`, generated the same error. Although specifying the encoding as `ISO-8859-1` did not return an error, the encoding was simply incorrect and the characters were all wrongly parsed.

```
> read_html(url, encoding = "EUC-JP")
Error in read_xml.raw(raw, encoding = encoding, base_url = base_url, as_html = as_html,  : 
  input conversion failed due to input error, bytes 0xAD 0xA1 0xCD 0xB9 [6003]
```

So how can I properly read this HTML webpage? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why declaring the encoding to be "EUC-JP" didn't work, but here's a roundabout way to read that URL:

```r
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.post.japanpost.jp/kitte_hagaki/stamp/kogata/index.php?p=4"
bytes <- readLines(url)
#> Warning in readLines(url): incomplete final line found on 'https://
#> www.post.japanpost.jp/kitte_hagaki/stamp/kogata/index.php?p=4'
utf8 <- iconv(bytes, from="EUC-JP", to="UTF-8")  
html <- read_html(charToRaw(paste(utf8, collapse="\n")), encoding="UTF-8")
html
#> {html_document}
#> <html lang="ja">
#> [1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 ...
#> [2] <body onload="SetInfo (0)">\n\n<div id="wrap-outer">\n<div id="wrap-inner ...
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for the workaround. It worked! Along the way I noticed a similar function `read_lines_raw()` function in the `readr` package. Unsure about the difference but would it fit in another version of the code snippet as well?

Comment: I don't know.  Try it!